# How to set the Background color while printing?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and C#. I am printing the entire aspx page into new window on button click.

This is my code..

```
    Page pg = new Page();
    pg.EnableEventValidation = false;
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    pg.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    pg.DesignerInitialize();
    pg.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    string strHTML = stringWrite.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTML);
```

This is working fine. Now i need that the printed page should have the same background color of the aspx page. Then the aspx page has some textbox. So i need that after printed the values in the textbox should not be able to change. Now by this code its changable.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Often browsers explicitly disable printing of background colors or background images. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Thanks.Then how to avoid that problem.Is there any way?

Comment: No! It should always be the client's choice. It's their print toner you'd be wasting!